# echo css styling

Tags: php, css

I have this echo, however I'm unsure how I'd style the echo with for instance a  tag. I'd appreciate some examples.

```
echo $lastpireps['landingrate'];
```

Additionally, is there anyway of styling this echo through a css file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<div class="foo"><?php echo $lastpireps['landingrate']; ?></div>
```

Or this:

```
echo '<div class="foo">' . $lastpireps['landingrate'] . '</div>';
```

And then style `.foo` in your css as normal.

Comment: Don't just `echo` variables to HTML markup; use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to prevent XSS.

Comment: Baby steps, Marcel. You're making a lot of assumptions, one being that the variable is from a form and was provided by someone other than the OP. Big assumption without seeing the `$_POST` anywhere

Comment: Oh no, all those baby steps here. Security isn't an afterthought, please teach someone how to do it the right way in one step. After all, it's not that difficult. Not only `$_POST` variables need to be encoded, all output should be encoded. Things will go wrong when there are `&`s or `<`s in that variable.

Comment: youc ould also use htmlentities

Comment: @user1681542: Yes, but `htmlentities` shouldn't be necessary if the encoding is correct.

Comment: What's your argument - encoding hiccups or XSS?

Comment: XSS of course. But even talking about HTML like `<b>` will go wrong when not properly encoded, resulting in unintended bold text.

Answer (score 0):

There are thousands of ways. Here's one.

If you're in a block/loop of php code

`echo "<div class='myclass'>".$lastpireps['landingrate']."</div>";`

In CSS

`.myclass {}`

Comment: Don't just `echo` variables to HTML markup; use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to prevent XSS.